# App crashing on first launch from play store

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent

App is working fine when i install it from android studio, but when i download it from `playstore`, it crashes on first launch, after that it works fine.

This is what i am getting in crash log.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver 
com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class"com.google. android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" 
on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories =[/data/app==/lib/arm64, /==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
```

I googled this, and updated my gradle file, but the crash is still there.

```
  force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.0.0'
  force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.0'
  force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:16.0.1'
  force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:16.0.1'
  force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:16.0.0'
```

I also added following in manifest file to avoid crash.

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can happen if the Google Play Services apk is not installed on the device, or too old for your app requirements.

You can check if the minimum Google Play Service version is available as follows:

```
Dialog errorDialog;

private boolean checkPlayServices() {

        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();

        int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this, minApkVersion);

        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {

                if (errorDialog == null) {
                    errorDialog = googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, 2404);
                    errorDialog.setCancelable(false);
                }

                if (!errorDialog.isShowing())
                    errorDialog.show();

            }
        }

        return resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}
```

`minApkVersion` is the minimum Google Play Service apk version required by your app.

And call this method in your app's Splash Screen's `onResume()`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        startApp();
    }
}
```